# Bootstrap 3.0 col border issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This seems like a ridiculous issue, but I can't seem to resolve it.

In Bootstrap 3.0, I'm simply using columns with a 1 pixel border.  Sometimes the border shows, but other times you have change the browsers window to see the border.

Since all the columns are in percentages, adding 1px border seems to be causing an issue.

Any advice?

[image]

[image]